# count values from different tables together

Tags: sql

I want to count the values from a table together minus the count values from another table. Per item/part

i have tried this:

```
SELECT SUM(receipt) AS "receipt"
FROM receipt WHERE item = '".$partnumber."'
group by item
```

and this works for one table, but how can i do this with 2 tables?

table receipt:

```
item | receipt
100    5
100    2
200    10
```

table sales

```
part | sold
100    2
```

output:

```
partnumber | stock
100          5
```

So i want to calculate the sum per item/part and at the and i want to do receipt-sold for the stock. How can i do this?

Comment: And what have you tried? How did it go?

Comment: You can do this via basic arithmetic using `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY`.  If you run into specific problems doing this, please post what isn't working.

Comment: @da1lbi3 Is there a reason you don't show item 200 on your output?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @Siyual No there is no reason for.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i use phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the sum the receipts:

```
SELECT item, SUM(receipt) receipt
FROM Table1 t1
GROUP BY item
```

then the sum of sales:

```
SELECT part, SUM(sold) sold
FROM Table2 t2
GROUP BY part
```

then join them together, taking the difference:

```
SELECT t1.item, (t1.receipt - COALESCE(t2.sold,0)) AS stock
FROM
(
    SELECT item, SUM(receipt) AS receipt
    FROM Table1 t1
    GROUP BY item
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT part, SUM(sold) AS sold
    FROM Table2 t2
    GROUP BY part
) t2
ON t1.item = t2.part
```

Note that the `COALESCE` will make sales 0 if there are no sales for a given part.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but his expected output does not show item 200, but this one will show that result as well.